# Why isn't my env variable passed to subscript in my bat script

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 scripts:

testEnv.bat:

```
set TEST_VAR = "hello"

call testEnvSub.bat
```

testEnvSub.bat:

```
echo %TEST_VAR%
```

When I run testEnv.bat, I just get:

"ECHO is on"

So clearly the env variable I set in testEnv isn't being passed to subscript. How do I get it to pass correctly?

Comment: I don't really consider what you are doing as "passing".  The called script inherits the environment from the parent process.  So any variables defined in the parent process are  available to the sub-process.  If you were really passing the variable then you would do this: `call testEnvSub.bat "%test_var%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** *"So clearly the env variable I set in testEnv isn't being passed to subscript."*

**Answer:** Not at all, the variable is created, you're just not calling the correct variable name, because you created it incorrectly.

**Question:** *"How do I get it to pass correctly?"*

**Answer:** Unlike C+, Perl etc. Windows `cmd` actually uses the whitespace as part of the variable name and value. So in fact, you created a variable called `%TEST_VAR %` instead of `%TEST_VAR%` and have a value of   `"hello"` including the leading whitespace.

So give this a go, note the double quotes starts before the variable name and closes after the value to eliminate whitespace creep.

```
@echo off
set "TEST_VAR=hello"
call testEnvSub.bat
```

Also, not that it makes much difference in execution, try and name your batch files with the `.cmd` extension instead of `.bat` it is sort off old fashioned.